# How to adapt Twitter Bootstrap´s css classes to drupal menus?

Tags: 7, routes

I´m traying to adapt the Twitter´s Bootstrap top menu to Drupal menu system. Up until now, unsuccessfully. I´m using Drupal module **nicemenus** to show them in dropdowns.

This is the hand made menu list using Bootstrap´s css:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 1
                <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-star"></i> Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-star"></i> Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Normal Menu Link without dropdown</a></li>      
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the Menu output with nicemenus, as you can see Bootstrap is so much easier to understand.

```
<div id="block-nice-menus-1" class="block block-nice-menus block-1 block-nice-menus-1 odd block-without-title">
  <div class="block-inner clearfix">

    <div class="content clearfix">
      <ul id="nice-menu-1" class="nice-menu nice-menu-down sf-js-enabled">
        <li class="menu-5674 menu-path-liganetnet  first   odd"><a href="">Link without Dropdowns</a></li>
        <li class="menu-267 menuparent  menu-path-front   even"><a style="dropdown" class="dropdown active" href="/">Dropdown Link 1</a>
            <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <li class="menu-2280 menu-path-node-196  first odd "><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-270 menu-path-node-197 even "><a title="" href="">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="menu-271 menu-path-node-1464   odd   last "><a title="" href="">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="menu-268 menuparent  menu-path-front   odd"><a class="active" href="/">Dropdown Link 2</a>
            <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <li class="menu-274 menu-path-node-214  first   odd  "><a title="" href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-273 menu-path-node-213   even  "><a title="" href="">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I´ve installed menu_attributes module, but when I add to it some classes they are added to the  tag only. How could I transform those css classes programatically?

Doing a print_r(), I´ve found this:

```
                            [sidebar_second] => Array
                                (
                                    [nice_menus_1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [#markup] => 

Link 1 without Dropdown
Dropdown 1
Dropdown 2
Dropdown 3



                                            [#contextual_links] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [block] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => admin/structure/block/manage
                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => nice_menus
                                                                    [1] => 1
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [#block] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [module] => nice_menus
                                                    [delta] => 1
                                                    [theme] => liganet
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                    [weight] => -62
                                                    [region] => sidebar_second
                                                    [custom] => 0
                                                    [visibility] => 0
                                                    [pages] => 
                                                    [title] => 
                                                    [bid] => 744
                                                    [cache] => -1
                                                    [subject] => 
                                                )
```

I thought that it could be done with the parent menu variable printed in the page template and then printing the children vars inside the classes? How may I do that with php?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### How to add/remove classes from menu output

Add the three functions below to the file *template.php* in your theme folder. Make sure the function names start with the name of your theme. The suffix `__main_menu` indicates the machine name of the menu you want to alter. Once the functions are added to your file, [clear all caches](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache).

1 ) [theme_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7). This adds the "nav" class to the `<ul>` element. If we left things here it would be applied to the parent and all child menus. Since we only want this applied to the parent, let's keep going.

```
function mytheme_menu_tree__main_menu($variables) {
  return '<ul class="nav">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

2 ) [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7). We have added only two lines to the original function which are commented below. The first adds the "dropdown" class to any `<li>` element that contains a child menu. The second declares a new theme wrapper specifically for the child menus.

You can optionally strip away existing classes with `$element['#attributes']['class'] = 'dropdown';` (remove the empty square brackets).

```
function mytheme_menu_link__main_menu($variables){
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    
    // Add class to this list element.
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown';

    // Declare a new theme wrapper for this list item's child menu.
    $element['#below']['#theme_wrappers'][0] = 'menu_tree__main_menu_children';
    
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

3 ) Custom theme function. This is our custom implementation of `theme_menu_tree` that we just declared above. It adds the class "dropdown-menu" to all child menus.

```
function mytheme_menu_tree__main_menu_children($variables) {
  return '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' . $variables['tree']    . '</ul>';
}
```

**Notes:**

- Be warned that removing classes could alter the functionality of the menu!
- This technique will only affect menu output; that is, everything between `<ul id="nice-menu-1">`..`</ul>` in the example pasted above. To remove the wrapper elements you should override [block.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) as described on this [handbook page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).

**More helpful links:**

- [About overriding themable output](https://www.drupal.org/node/173880) (Drupal.org Handbook)
- [Create a Foundation 5 'Top bar' menu in Drupal 7.x](http://othermachines.com/blog/create-foundation-5-top-bar-menu-drupal-7x) (a blog post of mine that uses the same technique, but for a Foundation menu)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Bootsrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and set this theme as base theme of your own theme. All menus will output as you need in this case, because Bootsrap theme has all rewrite functions